# How to test items with each other in 2 dimensional list?

Tags: python, nuke

We have a 2 dimensional list (for this example we have it populated with unique 6 nodes and 3 masks)

```
myList = [[node1, mask1], 
          [node2, mask1], 
          [node3, mask1], 
          [node4, mask2], 
          [node5, mask2], 
          [node6, mask3]]
```

Now i need to test each other somehow and generate a new list to put each node that is connected to a mask in a separate [], so i can easily access it later, but also i need to filter nodes like "node6" because "node6" is only connected to one mask (in our case with "mask3" only)

Basically i want my new list to look like this:

```
newList = [[node1, node2, node3], [node3, node4]]
```

This has been giving me headache for couple of hours now.. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

note: it would be nice to see also what is the most efficient way to do this

edit1: what i tried:

```
myList =[[node1, masks1][node2, mask1] etc..] #this is earlier dynamically populated with nodes/masks
newList= []
for i in range(len(myList)):
    for j in range(len(myList[i])):
        try:
            if myList[i][0] in newList:
                pass 
            elif myList[i][1] == myList[j][1] and len(myList) > 1:
                newList.append([db[i][0]])
                break
        except IndexError:
            #print 'passed error'
            pass
```

I know this dose not makes much sense for what i asked.. my previous attempts are not saved - in this example i tried to populate each node in a newlist that is connected to the same mask twice or more time.. but this is not working as expected.

Comment: You did not show what you tried.

Comment: @StephenRauch i edited my post now

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.groupby()` provides an efficient way to gather items:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_list = [['node1', 'mask1'],
          ['node2', 'mask1'],
          ['node3', 'mask1'],
          ['node4', 'mask2'],
          ['node5', 'mask2'],
          ['node6', 'mask3']]

masks_to_keep = ('mask1', 'mask2')

# create a dict keyed by mask with (node, mask) pairs
as_dict = {x[0]: list(x[1]) for x in groupby(my_list, lambda x: x[1])}

# create a list, in masks_to_keep order, of lists of nodes per mask
nodes = [[x[0] for x in as_dict[mask]] for mask in masks_to_keep]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though how would you do it without itertools (i am doing this code for nuke, i'd prefer it without itertools for starters..

Comment: You included masks_to_keep = ('mask1', 'mask2') - but the thing is i need to check this programmatically  = every mask that more than onc node is connected to, in our example is mask1 and mask2 true.. though how would oyu include it in the code?

Comment: Really?  itertools is part of the python stdlib since 2.3.  Use it, because it is wonderful.  Also, you did not give me any more info as to what 'node' or 'mask' was.  So I used strings.  Python being the wonderful language that it is, does not care as long as these items are immutable. It will just work.  So put the masks you want to keep into a list or tuple, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Oh you are right about itertools i mixed it up with NumPy... Great :)

Though about what masks or nodes are -- i think it's not relevant (but they are actual nodes in the GUI software Nuke - by The Foundry which i am trying to access and store in lists etc..

The list in my example shows each "node" with it's corresponding connecting "mask".. 

Not to write the same please read again my original post "Now i need to test each other somehow and generate a new list..." so i think it dosen't matter what they are but the logic that i can't work out, especially not now with your code :) Thanks

Comment: Something like this: