# How to test each element in a list (with little more complex logic)?

Tags: python, nuke

I have a list that is dynamically generated:

```
myList = [[node1, mask1],
          [node2, mask1], 
          [node3, mask1], 
          [node4, mask2], 
          [node5, mask2], 
          [node6, mask3],
          [node7, mask4],
         ]
```

Note: each node/mask in the list are actual Nodes in the software GUI, that I am trying to access and manipulate later. I think representing them as strings for now, would serve the purpose fine.

Rules:

1. I must logically compare each item in the list with each other to get the result;
2. keep all the nodes except those that have connection to only one type of mask, in this example, node6, and 7, needs to be excluded and get the following result:

   ```
   newList = [[node1, node2, node3], [node4, node5]]
   ```

Optional: I would also like to keep some information of each node to what mask has been connected so I can use that later - but I can think of other solutions to this so it's optional.

I tried looping through each element with nested for loops but that misses some cases. I also tried working with `groupby()`, but I can't figure it out, as my Python knowledge is limited.

Comment: Please stop literally banging your head. Go for a walk.

Comment: why `[node5, mask2]` is missed from the result? `[node4, mask2], 
          [node5, mask2]` have a common "mask"

Comment: Why is node3 represented twice?  How does this differ from the question you asked yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421039/how-to-test-items-with-each-other-in-2-dimensional-list/41421176#41421176

Comment: @StephenRauch my mistake typo thanks.. i corrected it now

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it was typo sorry - fixed it now

Comment: @jbasko i already did that couple of times lol - not helping in my case ...sadly

Comment: you could just sort the list by mask (as you have in the example), then iterate over items and make groups together items that appear in sequences longer than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group all nodes with same mask into a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

myList = [['node1', 'mask1'],
          ['node2', 'mask1'], 
          ['node3', 'mask1'], 
          ['node4', 'mask2'], 
          ['node5', 'mask2'], 
          ['node6', 'mask3'],
          ['node7', 'mask4'],
         ]

# create a hash with key as mask
# and value as list of nodes with that mask 
node_gps = defaultdict(list)
for item in myList:
    node = item[0]
    mask = item[1]
    node_gps[mask].append(node)

print node_gps
# =>  {'mask4': ['node7'], 
#      'mask1': ['node1', 'node2', 'node3'], 
#      'mask3': ['node6'], 
#      'mask2': ['node4', 'node5']}


# filter out nodes with only one match
# using list comprehension
newList =  [v for k, v in node_gps.items() if len(v) > 1]

# or using for loops
newList = []
# iterate over each mask, nodes pair in node_gps
for mask, nodes in node_gps.items():
    # append a node_list if it has more than 1 node
    if len(nodes) > 1:
        newList.append(nodes)

print newList
# [['node1', 'node2', 'node3'], 
#  ['node4', 'node5']]
```

The `node_gps` dict also stores the mask associated with each list of nodes.

Comment: WoW that was fast! @tihom so fast! Thanks i was looking for this exactly!

Comment: though how would you write the line print [v for k, v in node_gps.items() if len(v) > 1]   -  with for loops (in a more general way - it's a little cloudy for me when i look at that

Comment: @masky007 update the answer with for loop version of the list comprehension. I would recommend learning about list comprehensions as they are used in many places and would make it easier for you to understand code written by others.

Comment: thank you and i will do that - i'v seen it so many times.. Can you recommend me some book actually to learn about all the stuff in a nice order - up till now i have been learning stuff as i need by trial/error and google

Comment: @masky007 I don't know of good books. I have learned by trial/error so far.